# crop image in skimage?

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I'm using skimage to crop a rectangle in a given image, now I have (x1,y1,x2,y2) as the rectangle coordinates, then I had loaded the image

```
 image = skimage.io.imread(filename)
 cropped = image(x1,y1,x2,y2)
```

However this is the wrong way to crop the image, how would I do it in the right way in skimage

Answer (score 28):

This seems a simple syntax error.

Well, in Matlab you can use `_'parentheses'_` to extract a pixel or an image region. But in Python, and `numpy.ndarray` you should use the brackets to slice a region of your image, besides in this code you is using the wrong way to cut a rectangle.

The right way to cut is using the `:` operator.

Thus,

```
from skimage import io
image = io.imread(filename)
cropped = image[x1:x2,y1:y2]
```

Comment: Isn't `image[y1:y2, x1:x2]` more correct here, given that x refers to the horizontal axis?

Answer (score 11):

One could use `skimage.util.crop()` function too, as shown in the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.util import crop
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

A = imread('lena.jpg')

# crop_width{sequence, int}: Number of values to remove from the edges of each axis. 
# ((before_1, after_1), … (before_N, after_N)) specifies unique crop widths at the 
# start and end of each axis. ((before, after),) specifies a fixed start and end 
# crop for every axis. (n,) or n for integer n is a shortcut for before = after = n 
# for all axes.
B = crop(A, ((50, 100), (50, 50), (0,0)), copy=False)

print(A.shape, B.shape)
# (220, 220, 3) (70, 120, 3)

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(A), plt.axis('off') 
plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(B), plt.axis('off') 
plt.show()
```

with the following output (with original and cropped image):

[image]

Comment: Extra kudos for using this classic old-school photo editing pic!

Answer (score 2):

You can crop image using skimage just by slicing the image array like below:

```
image = image_name[y1:y2, x1:x2]
```

Example Code :

```
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = io.imread(image_path)
cropped_image = image[y1:y2, x1:x2]
plt.imshow(cropped_image)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can go ahead with the Image module of the PIL library

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("image.png")
im = im.crop((0, 50, 777, 686))
im.show()
```

Comment: `Image` not `image` in `from PIL import image`

Comment: The question is specifically about skimage.